# Apache HTTPD as a proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I need to redirect all the requests from
localhost:8080/app1/ to localhost/app1.

which is the best way to do it.

The only requirement is that the user must never be aware that he is accessing the application at port 80. i guess I need to set up Apache HTTPD proxying - I'm just not sure which is the best way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=apache+proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full example, it's what I use to frontend `apt-proxy` with an apache that's already using port 80.

You need to put this either inside the relevent VirtualHost directive.

```
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPass               / http://127.0.0.1:1723/
    ProxyPassReverse        / http://127.0.0.1:1723/

    <Proxy http://127.0.0.1:1723/>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from none
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
```

You may also need to run `a2enmod proxy` if the proxy module isn't enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "reverse proxy" configuration.  Check the mod_proxy docs, look at ProxyPass.